# Visualization of data - revenue trend monthly with missing customer data

Tags: postgresql, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I have a conceptual issue of how to manipulate data to overcome missing customer data for a certain month relaying the revenues of that customer since they began business (this is a crucial point). I always need to take the last report and only show it, otherwise i'm doubling up data.
I'm showing the revenues trend on a monthly basis, the problem is if a customer doesn't show us the revenues in a given month, the following month the revenues will not include the revenues from that customer from the previous month. So basically, i'm trying to figure out how to carry over the revenues of a customer to the following months even when no revenues have been reported that month. I'm trying to visualise this in a chart.

This is an example of the data structure in the database:

```
date    |     customer |  revenues
08/2017        A            100
08/2017        B            125
09/2017        A            200
09/2017        B            200
10/2017        A            450
10/2017        B            220
10/2017        C            180
11/2017        A            700
11/2017        C            250
```

Current Outcome:

```
08/2017 - total 225  - A 100, B 125
09/2017 - total 400  - A 200, B 200
10/2017 - total 850  - A 450, B 220, C 180
11/2017 - total 880 - A 700, C 180
```

Wanted Outcome:

```
08/2017 - total 225 -  A 100, B 125
09/2017 - total 400 -  A 200, B 200
10/2017 - total 850 -  A 450, B 220, C 180
11/2017 - total 1170 - A 700, B 220, C 180
```

I'm wondering what I should to I'm trying to use either PostgreSQL or using a visualisation tool.

How can I automatically model it (whether in a View or another method) so that the data applied each month contains all customers' latest revenue (carrying it forward if data doesn't exist for that customer that month).

Answer (score 0):

You may create a view with a query like this in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT 
        date_t, 
        COALESCE(sum_a,0) + COALESCE(sum_b,0) + COALESCE(sum_c,0) Total, 
        SUM_A, 
        SUM_B, 
        SUM_C
FROM 
        ( SELECT 
                date_t,
                CASE 
                        WHEN LAG(sum_A,1) OVER ( ORDER BY date_t ) IS NOT NULL 
                                AND sum_A    IS NULL
                        THEN LAG(sum_A,1) OVER ( ORDER BY date_t )
                        ELSE sum_A 
                END SUM_A,
                CASE 
                        WHEN LAG(sum_B,1) OVER ( ORDER BY date_t ) IS NOT NULL 
                                AND sum_B    IS NULL
                        THEN LAG(sum_B,1) OVER ( ORDER BY date_t )
                        ELSE sum_B 
                END SUM_B,
                CASE 
                        WHEN LAG(sum_C,1) OVER ( ORDER BY date_t ) IS NOT NULL 
                                AND sum_C    IS NULL
                        THEN LAG(sum_C,1) OVER ( ORDER BY date_t )
                        ELSE sum_C 
                END SUM_C
        FROM 
                ( select 
                        date_t,
                        SUM ( CASE 
                                WHEN customer = 'A' 
                                THEN revenues 
                        END ) sum_A,
                        SUM ( CASE 
                                WHEN customer = 'B' 
                                THEN revenues 
                        END ) sum_B,
                        SUM ( CASE 
                                WHEN customer = 'C' 
                                THEN revenues 
                        END ) sum_C
                FROM 
                        yourtable
                GROUP BY 
                        date_t
                ) s1 
        )         s2
ORDER BY 
        date_t;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/524c3/26)

The `LAG()` function checks for the previous row - in your case the sum.